# Django - Cannot Create Follower Functionality

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a project similar to a social media site, where users can go to a user profile, and 'follow' another user profile. When I click 'follow' on the profile, currently I don't get any errors at all. Nothing happens. I don't see anything in my console/terminal etc. There's no error. Help is appreciated!

views.py

```
def fol(request, username):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        currentuser = request.user
        profileuser = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=profileuser).order_by('id').reverse()
        follower = Follow.objects.filter(target=profileuser)
        following = Follow.objects.filter(follower=profileuser)

        following_each_other = Follow.objects.filter(follower=currentuser, target=profileuser)
        totalfollower = len(follower)
        totalfollowing = len(following)

        paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context = {
            'posts': posts.count(),
            'profileuser': profileuser,
            'follower': follower,
            'totalfollower': totalfollower,
            'following': following,
            'totalfollowing': totalfollowing,
            'followingEachOther': following_each_other
        }
        return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
    else:
        currentuser = request.user
        profileuser = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=profileuser).order_by('id').reverse()
        following_each_other = Follow.objects.filter(follower=currentuser, target=profileuser)

        paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        if not following_each_other:
            f = Follow.objects.create(target=profileuser, follower=currentuser)
            f.save()
            follower = Follow.objects.filter(target=profileuser)
            following = Follow.objects.filter(follower=profileuser)
            following_each_other = Follow.objects.filter(follower=request.user, target=profileuser)
            totalfollower = len(follower)
            totalfollowing = len(following)

            context = {
                'posts': posts.count(),
                'profileuser': profileuser,
                'page_obj': page_obj,
                'follower': follower,
                'following': following,
                'totalfollowing': totalfollowing,
                'totalfollower': totalfollower,
                'followingEachOther': following_each_other
            }

            return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
    
        else:
            following_each_other.delete()
            follower = Follow.objects.filter(target=profileuser)
            following = Follow.objects.filter(follower=profileuser)
            totalfollower = len(follower)
            totalfollowing = len(following)

            context = {
                'posts': posts.count(),
                'profileuser': profileuser,
                'page_obj': page_obj,
                'follower': follower,
                'following': following,
                'totalfollowing': totalfollowing,
                'totalfollower': totalfollower,
                'followingEachOther': following_each_other
            }
   
            return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("fol/<str:username>", views.fol, name="fol"),
    path("following_list/<str:username>", views.following_list, name='following_list'),
    path("profile/<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

html file for the profile:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}

{% if message %}
        <h4 class="message">{{message}}</h4>
{% endif %}
   
    <h3> You are viewing {{ profileuser.username }}'s profile. </h3> <br>
   

<br>

{% if user1 != user2 %}
<div class="pull-right">
  <a href="{% url 'fol' username=profileuser.username %}"></a><input class="btn btn-primary" 
type="submit" value="Follow">
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Unfollow">
</div>
{% endif %}

{% for i in page_obj %}

<div class='card mb-3' style="max-width: 530px;" id="card-posts">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'profile' username=i.username %}">. 
   {{i.username}}</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{i.text}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{i.timestamp}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{i.amount_likes}}</p>
             
                    <div class="like mt-3">
                    <img
                    data-id="{{i.id}}"
                    id="post-like-{{i.id}}"
                      class="liked"
                      {% if not request.user in i.like.all %}
                      data-is_liked="no"
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/452/white-heart.png"
              {%else%}
              data-is_liked="yes"
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/452/red-heart.png"
                      {%endif%}
                    />
                    <span id="post-count-{{i.id}}">{{i.like.count}}</span>
              </div>
              <br>
              {% if user1 == user2 %}
              <span class="text-primary edit" data-id="{{i.id}}" id="edit-btn-{{i.id}}">Edit</span>
              <br><br>
              {% endif %}

              <span id="post-content-{{i.id}}" class="post" >{{i.post}}</span>
     <textarea data-id="{{i.id}}" id="post-edit-{{i.id}}" style="display:none;" class="form-control textarea" row="3">{{i.post}}</textarea>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

{% endfor %}
<br><br>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}  
          <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" 
          class="page-link">Previous</a>
       {% else %}
  
  <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if page_obj.number %}
  <a class="page-link">{{ page_obj.number }}</a>
  {% else %}
  <a class="page-link">0</a>
  {% endif %}

     {% if page_obj.has_next %}
  <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">Next</a>

  {% else %}
  <a class="page-link">Next</a>
  {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', 
        null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
       User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Follow(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='targets')
```